# Components in start-all.sh asking for password at start-up

Tags: linux, hadoop, ssh, linux-mint

Using [this](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/) article, I installed Hadoop on my MINT machine. Everything has been successfully installed but not configured, I think. I have a separate user account for Hadoop configuration, called `hduser`, apart from my own admin user account called `nkhl`. Now,

1. When I `ssh localhost` when I am in `nkhl`, it works fine (meaning it doesn't ask for a password)
2. When I `ssh localhost` when I am in `hduser`, it *asks* for a password (I don't know if I am supposed to do it).

Logically, I think my ssh has been installed/configured correctly, as it does not ask for a password when I am in `nkhl`.

BUT, when I `start-all.sh`, from `hduser`, at each component startup, I am asked to input the password. When I shut them off too, I am asked for it. Can you help me please?!

Answer (score 0):

Each user has his keys stored into the folder .ssh in his home directory, you have to build again the ssh key for hduser.

Rapeat the procedure you did for mkhl user also for hduser.

Comment: Thanks. I signed out of my NKHL user, and signed into hduser and I was thrown an error that read  "Cinnamon has crashed. You're in fallback mode" or something like that. Could this be happening because of that?